# UIImagePickerController Memory Leak Issue, .camera is good, but not for .photoLibrary

Tags: swift, uiimagepickercontroller

UIImagePickerController Memory Leak Issue, .camera is good, but not for .photoLibrary

Here is the code:

```
func PickLibraryTapped() {
    if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.photoLibrary) {
        let LibraryPhotoPicker = UIImagePickerController()
        LibraryPhotoPicker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
        LibraryPhotoPicker.delegate = self
        LibraryPhotoPicker.allowsEditing = false
        self.present(LibraryPhotoPicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    else
    {
        print("模拟其中无法打开照相机,请在真机中使用");
    }
}
```

Delegate method:

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
    let info = convertFromUIImagePickerControllerInfoKeyDictionary(info)
    let pickedImage = info[convertFromUIImagePickerControllerInfoKey(UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage)] as! UIImage
    picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion:nil)
}
```

Errors:
Device popup a alertview indicating that "Memory Leak" and "Object Deallocated" (UIImagePickerController)

```
In case that UIImagePickerController should not be dealloced, override -willDealloc in UIImagePickerController by returning NO.
```

UPDATE!!!:

Problem Solved:
The Issue was raised because pod "MLeakFinder" been used, after Unistall MLeakFinder the pop up alert is gone.  The Code has no error.

Reminder:
convertFromUIImagePickerControllerInfoKeyDictionary is no more use in this code.
Should Try Below:

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
    if let pickedImage = info[.originalImage] as? UIImage {
        //Do something you need
    }
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Can you provide more information for this??

Comment: For .camera it works fine , but for .photolibrary UIImagePickerController dealloced right after UIImagePickerController.dismiss been called. no idea why is that

Comment: If you need "let LibraryPhotoPicker = UIImagePickerController()" even after dismissing it!! then declare it globally.